# Linq join two objects of the same type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join

How can I get this to work? I keep getting the error message that r does not exist in the current context (where I put the **).

```
                    var query = (
                        from p in PrerequisitesList
                        join r in RequirementStatus
                        on p.ID equals r.ID
                        into temp
                        from r in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new RequirementStatus(p.ID, p.Name, p.Description, **r.Fulfilled**))
                        select new
                        {
                            p.ID
                            ,p.Name
                            ,p.Description
                            ,r.Fulfilled
                        });
```

Both types are exactly the same so the individual values get overwritten.

Comment: By "exactly the same" do you mean "have exactly the same properties"?

Comment: @ D Stanley - Correct
@ AD.Net - It does not, I get a precompile error.

Comment: @CBauer just because two types have the same properties does not mean they are the same type.  You can't just join them as if they were collections of the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `DefaultIfEmpty` essentially provides a left outer join. This means that it is your fallback if the join doesn't find a match in the right sequence. If the right item is null, we cannot really access it, right?

You have to figure out something else, because you have made a logical mistake.

Maybe you can solve it by actually providing a default value?

Something like this:

```
temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new RequirementStatus(p.ID, p.Name, p.Description, false))
```

Besides, the right list is named the same as the `RequirementStatus` type later used, which makes your example uncompilable. But that's probably a typo.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you use 2 `r`s in your query, the `r` in the `select new` may refer to the `r` in `join r` and it's out of scope. You have to use another name instead either way.

```
var query = ( from p in PrerequisitesList
              join r in RequirementStatus on p.ID equals r.ID into temp
              from r2 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new RequirementStatus(p.ID, p.Name, p.Description, p.Fulfilled))
              select new {
                        p.ID,
                        p.Name,
                        p.Description,
                        r2.Fulfilled
              });
```

Comment: Appreciate the notice, but the error persists on the 3rd line.

Comment: @CBauer even when you have access to `r` that way, it makes no sense because when the `temp` is empty, you don't have any `r` grouped, so how you can access it? I think you mean `p.Fulfilled`, not `r.Fulfilled`